# excel vba form is closed but I can't switch to other .xlsm workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook "A" with a macro and set with a shortcut "Ctrl+Q", when I press "Ctrl+Q" the a form pops up, and when I press "ESC" the form is closed since I added a button "CommandButton1" whose property "Cancel" set to `TRUE`.

In the code I close the form like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

It works well, but the problem is I can't switch to other opened workbooks until I close the workbook "A", does anyone knows what the problem is?

thanks very much!

the code is like this:

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin {C62A69F0-16DC-11CE-9E98-00AA00574A4F} Get_Photo 
   Caption         =   "abc"
   ClientHeight    =   3120
   ClientLeft      =   45
   ClientTop       =   435
   ClientWidth     =   4710
   OleObjectBlob   =   "Get_Photo.frx":0000
   StartUpPosition =   1  'CenterOwner
End
Attribute VB_Name = "Get_Photo"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Get_Photo
        .Caption = caption_Name
        .Width = 430
        .Height = 270
    End With

    With WebBrowser1
        .Width = 540
        .Height = 300
        .Navigate ("www.google.com/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif")
    End With

End Sub
```

The above form contains a webbrowser and a cancel button.
I added a button in a worksheet with the macro code `Get_Photo.Show`
when click the button, the form will show with a picture in it.
but when I closed the form after pressing "ESC", I can't then switch to other xlsm workbooks, but xlsx workbooks are fine..

Comment: If you mean you cant switch books while your `UserForm` is shown then this is normal as by default Workbooks are model. If you call your `UserForm` like `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` then you can switch books while during an active `Userform`.  Or are you saying you can switch books at all until Workbook A is closed (ie regardless of whether the form is open)?

Comment: @aaron: I am unable to reproduce this behavior. It works fine on my pc. I believe the problem is somewhere else. Can you post the Userform and the Macro Code?

Comment: @brettdj, thanks, it's true we can't switch workbook when the dialog (which is not modeless) is shown, but now (sorry for unclear description), I mean switching workbook after the dialog is closed.

Comment: @Siddharth, thanks, I will try to reproduce with a simple workbook, will update you later.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I added more comments to reproduce the problem

Comment: Finally, I have been able to reproduce it :) Let me check on it and get back to you. I was not able to switch to other `xlsm/xlsx` workbook. It kept on showing me the original workbook. The `Alt+Tab` also refused to work. It's doesn't make any exception if I press the commandbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > @SiddharthRout, I added more comments to reproduce the problem – aaron 30 mins ago
> > >
> > > Finally, I have been able to reproduce it :) Let me check on it and get back to you. I was not able to switch to other xlsm/xlsx workbook. It kept on showing me the original workbook. The Alt+Tab also refused to work. It's doesn't make any exception if I press the commandbutton. – Siddharth Rout 1 min ago edit

I cannot explain the behavior. Probably it is a bug (*However, I haven't seen any documentation on it yet*).

This will solve your problem. (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

Put this 2 extra lines of code in the button code of the worksheet from where you are calling the useeform.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
    Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = False
    Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = True
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid